# Modifying parent classes variables

Tags: haxe, openfl

Iv looked around online for a solution to this issue but iv been unable to solve it.

I want to extend the sprite class to make my own interactive circle. Everything works but setting the X,Y, Width and height of the custom class does not work:

```
class CircleDraw extends Sprite
{

public function new(x:Int,y:Int,width:Int,height:Int)
{
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    drawCircle();
}

private function drawCircle()
{
    this.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
    this.graphics.drawCircle(this.x,this.y, this.width);
    this.graphics.endFill();
}
}
```

The approach above does not work as expected, setting x,y and width via the constructor results in literally nothing appearing. Yet if i set them manually, either within the class

```
this.graphics.drawCircle(200,200, 30);
```

Or prior to addChild:

```
 circle = new CircleDraw(10,10,100,200);
 circle.x=100;
 circle.y=100;
```

it then appears on screen. also after adding it like so once the values have been added manually within the class rather than this.x etc:

```
circle = new CircleDraw(10,10,100,200);
addChild(circle);
```

So my question is this, how do i extend a class (Sprite) and allow the constructor to modify its parents default variables and keep the values?

### EDIT

Just to provide all the code as requested:

This does not work:

```
    circle = new CircleDraw(10,10,100,200);
    addChild(circle);
```

when Circle draw is like this:

```
class CircleDraw extends Sprite
{
    public function new(x:Int,y:Int,width:Int,height:Int)
    {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        drawCircle();
    }

    private function drawCircle()
    {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(this.x, this.y, this.width);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }

}
```

It does work if i modify the method:

```
private function drawCircle()
        {
            this.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
            this.graphics.drawCircle(200, 200, 30);
            this.graphics.endFill();
        }
```

Or if during the instancing of the object i set the X and Y variables as mentioned before the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed setting the base class variables successfully, it's just that `DisplayObject.width` has a rather specific (and perhaps not that obvious) behavior.

> **`width:Float`**
>
> Indicates the width of the display object, in pixels. The width is calculated based on the bounds of the content of the display object. When you set the width property, the `scaleX` property is adjusted accordingly, as shown in the following code:
>
> Except for TextField and Video objects, a display object with no content(such as an empty sprite) has a width of 0, even if you try to set `width` to a different value.
>   —[OpenFL API: DisplayObject: width](http://api.openfl.org/openfl/display/DisplayObject.html#width)

In this sense, OpenFL follows the [ActionScript 3.0 API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width).

Comment: That means you cannot manually set the width value. In other words, OP is drawing a circle with zero radius. This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the (partial) code you posted, it looks it should work.

In other words, setting parent's variables like that should work.

I doubt there are some other code you didn't post gets in the way. I suggest you print out the x, y values in the drawCircle call to debug.

I also doubt the circle is drawn off-screen so you can't see it. Because you first moved the sprite, to (x,y) and then draw a circle in (x,y) inside the sprite. So effectively the circle is at (2x,2y) in global space

**EDIT:**

```
this.graphics.drawCircle(200,200, 30);
```

You claim this worked. Should draw at (210,210) with radius 30

```
circle = new CircleDraw(10,10,100,200);
circle.x=100;
circle.y=100;
```

You claim this worked. Should draw at (200,200) with radius 100

```
circle = new CircleDraw(10,10,100,200);
addChild(circle);
```

You claim this didn't work. Should draw at (20,20) with radius 100

From the above three version, you are actually drawing at different places with different sizes. So I still suspect that "didn't work" may due to the fact that you are drawing at some places not in sight.

So I still suggest you print out the value of x, y, width inside the private drawCircle function to see what's happening

Answer (score 2):

From what I can surmise, it looks like you're trying to override a constructor (new) that takes no arguments.

I'm not entirely sure, but that might not get you what you want. What I think you're actually doing is just creating a method "new" on the extended class, and then within it, feeding the parent nothing (super()). So the parent will not have the constructor arguments. It would be interesting to do look at that object in a debugger and look at the instance properties vs. the parent ones.

There's probably a way around that, but I think you might want to look at doing this via composition instead of inheritance. For example, in "new", create a new instance of a sprite, and manipulate the properties of that.

```
class MySprite
{
    public var sprite : Sprite;

    public function new ( ) {
        sprite = new Sprite ();
    }
}
```

You would then perform your operations on that sprite instance. Essentially, you are just wrapping a sprite in your own class. Decorator, more or less.

I found some reference to the topic here (it's been a while since I did any Flash programming), it shows addChild and removeChild implementations, etc.

http://old.haxe.org/forum/thread/685

Comment: This seems an interesting way, but if i use a sprite instance wouldnt i have to use a getter method to return the sprite as an object to add to the screen? I would like to extend the original sprite class so i can directly addChild(MySprite) if that makes sense

Comment: Yah look at that article. You just have to create the addChild implementation for your sprite wrapper. I get that what you want to do is deal with this class more or less just like a sprite class. The one concession might be, you have to do MySprite.getSprite or something like that. Otherwise you'd just mirror the API of sprite and get what you want. I remember in the past dealing with something like this and I eventually figured that as a rule, it's better to deal with these sorts of things via composition.

Comment: Ah thanks, that actually explains the problem very well. it seems odd at first though to not be able to deal with it in the way you would expect but makes sense due to platform restrictions....still its inconvenient that there is no on the box warning as it were as id spent some time trying to figure this out without composition assuming it was a programming logic problem. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah that call would be addChild ( new MySprite ( ).sprite ). Then everything else would be the same.

Comment: No problem at all glad to help. I used to do a LOT of Flash programming (I mean everything, games, enterprise tools, commercial UIs, you name it). At one point in time I had handwritten libraries for all this stuff and for the native drawing objects I almost always used composition.

Comment: its a good fix, but from a programming perspective doesent it make your own API less intuitive in the end? My experience is primarily with java and c sharp so havent had these particular issues before with inheritance

Comment: I guess that's a matter of perspective. If you were to call the class "SpriteWrapper" or "ManagedSprite", then you'd expect to have to use a getter or access a public member. It would also communicate clearly that this is not a native sprite object, but something managing one. There's other examples, in Scala say, when accessing a JSONObject, you can't just access the JSONObject instance to turn it into a Map, you have to use "new JSONObject ( ).get". There's a reason for that (a good one), but to the strict OOP Java type, it can seem completely wonky.

Comment: No, this "solution" doesn't answer the OP. As I said, OP's way of assigning variables like that *should* work. There must be something happening somewhere to make it not behave as expected.

Comment: "I think it should but it doesn't and I don't know why" isn't useful at all. You might also want to read the Haxe docs on the subject.

Comment: I'm afraid @KevinResoL is correct.  *The OP's way of assigning variables does work*.  The issue he's experiencing is related to `width` being a property with a very specific `get`/`set` behavior.

Comment: Enjoy your down vote capability, and have a nice day.

Comment: I don't deny workaround that "just works". I just believe that fully understanding the root cause is more important, and almost always lead to more optimal solution. In this case, allocating an extra object as the wrapper isn't optimal, as it uses more memory, cpu, etc. On the contrast, knowing the root cause (say you can't set the width of a sprite) and simply use other ways to specify the circle size, would save you from that extra overhead.

Comment: Ok. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware, that you are kind of dealing with 2 coordinate spaces. The one were the Sprite will be added and the graphics object of that Sprite. If you set `this.x` and `this.width` you are actually setting properties of this Sprite. So in regards of positing you are moving the Sprite itself in that case. The Sprite "graphics" property has it's own coordinate space.

For example if you pass `x=100` in your CircleDraw constructor function you are first moving the sprite itself by `x=100` and then draw the circle with an x offset of 100. So if you would add the sprite directly to the Stage you would start drawing your circle actually at `x=200`, because you effectively applied the position twice. It seems to me this is not what you actually are intending.

Also your CircleDraw instance (which is also a Sprite of course) is "empty" when you are constructing it. So calling `this.width = width` in your constructor has no effect. `this.width` will stay 0 because the Sprite has no contents at that point. So in the drawCircle method you are drawing a circle with a `width` of 0.

Probably the better solution would be to simply pass the arguments of your constructor function to your drawCircle function, without setting any properties.